# How to filter ManyToManyField in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a model Offlinecheckout and CartItem model. I want to add a filter queryset of the cart field in the offline checkout model. As It is showing the cart of all users. I want to filter queryset by request.user.So that cart filed will show in the cart request.user only not other users.

How I can add a filter in that field.

[image]

***Models.py***

```
class OfflineCheckOut(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ManyToManyField('cart.CartItem')
    time_slot = models.ForeignKey('category.TimeSlot', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    landmark = models.CharField(max_length=254, blank=True)
    # order_id = models.ForeignKey('cart.CartModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    tsn_amount = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('CartModel', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service = models.ForeignKey('accounts.SubCategory', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    defects = models.ForeignKey('category.Defects', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

***serializers.py***

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Address, Date, OfflineCheckOut

class OfflineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = OfflineCheckOut
        fields = "__all__"
```

***views.py***

```
class offlineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active and user.is_superuser or user.is_Customer:
                    return OfflineCheckOut.objects.all()
                raise PermissionDenied()
            raise PermissionDenied()
        raise PermissionDenied()

    serializer_class = OfflineSerializer
```

Comment: Hello Can you please share **CartItem** model?

Comment: yes updated please check again

Answer (score 0):

You can filter relations by using `FilteredRelation` in Django

Please change your **views.py** as follow

```
from django.db.models import FilteredRelation, Q

class offlineViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        if user.is_authenticated:
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active and user.is_superuser or user.is_Customer:
                     ### Use filtered relation 
                    return OfflineCheckOut.objects.filter(user=user).annotate(user_cart=FilteredRelation('cart', condition=Q(cart__user=user)))   
                raise PermissionDenied()
            raise PermissionDenied()
        raise PermissionDenied()

    serializer_class = OfflineSerializer
```

I hope this will help you to resolve an issue.

Please refer [FilteredRelation objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filteredrelation-objects) for more information.

If you require further help please comment

Comment: bro I want to add Filter in cart Field in OfflineCheckout model

Comment: I want to list the request.user cart only in the field

Comment: yes I is not working as it shows all the cart of all user in cart ManyToMany field

Comment: you can get it in `user_cart` from the queryset returned by `OfflineCheckOut.objects.filter(user=user).annotate(user_cart=FilteredRelation('cart', condition=Q(cart__user=user)))  `